# Why does this CUDA program crash when I write to device memory?

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm a CUDA beginner trying to write to device memory from the GPU so that I can copy it back to the host and see the results.

This is my code, which I stripped down as small as I could while still getting the error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool verbose = true;
int SIZE = 10;

__global__
void assign_state(uint8_t * states)
{
    states[threadIdx.x] = 42;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

    // Create host states vector
    if (verbose) std::cout << "Creating host memory... ";

    std::vector<uint8_t> * states = new std::vector<uint8_t>(SIZE);
    int statesSize = states->size() * sizeof(uint8_t);

    if (verbose) std::cout << "Done\n";

    // Send data to device
    if (verbose) std::cout << "Sending graph to device... ";

    uint8_t * deviceStatesPointer;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceStatesPointer, statesSize);
    cudaMemcpy(deviceStatesPointer, states, statesSize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    if (verbose) std::cout << "Done\n";

    // Assign states
    if (verbose) std::cout << "Assign states... ";

    dim3 dimBlock(SIZE, 1);
    dim3 dimGrid(1, 1);
    assign_state<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(deviceStatesPointer);

    if (verbose) std::cout << "Done\n";

    // Get data back from device
    if (verbose) std::cout << "Getting data back from device...\n";

    cudaMemcpy(states, deviceStatesPointer, statesSize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    if (verbose)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < states->size(); i++)
        {
            std::cout << "\t" << i << ": " << states->at(i) << std::endl;

        }
    }

    if (verbose) std::cout << "Done\n";

    return 0;
}
```

It works as long as I comment out the `states[threadIdx.x] = 42'` line, but if I don't, the program crashes right after printing out the first iteration of the for loop.

From what I've seen online, I'm guessing I might be trying to write to memory I'm not supposed to write to?

I've been basing my code off [this Hello World example](http://computer-graphics.se/hello-world-for-cuda.html).

Comment: this: `new std::vector` is nonsense

Answer (score 1):

The reason may well be your invalid memory access when "copying" the contents of the vector.

You are `cudaMemcpy`'ing from source address `states`. That *is not* the address of the *contents* of your `std::vector`, it is the address of where your `std::vector`'s data members are. One of these data members is, generally, a pointer into the [heap area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(programming)) - allocated when you create the vector or resize it. You have to pass *that* pointer to `cudaMemcpy` (e.g. `states.cbegin()` or `&states[0]`).

Please read up on how to use the standard vector class (e.g. [on cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), although that's more of a reference site than a tutorial); you don't need a `new` for it either - that will only give you an `std::vector` on the heap, and the result of that `new` is not the area where the data will reside (which you do not allocate yourself).